# Python 2.7 Search Dictionary A with key from Dictionary B

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

My project:  Pull an "ID" from a file name.  Use a CSV with ID to encrypt and email encrypted file.  I'm starting with building a dictionary for ID: Filename, and ID: Email, Password.  I need to take the ID from FileName and look up the entry in EmailList with that same ID key. Once I have the correct Key, Value pair from the EmailList dictionary, I will encrypt and then email the file based on the value entries in that pair. Here is what I've got that is getting me an error:

```
for ID in FileList():
    for k in EmailList():
        if ID in k: print ID
        else : print "Nothing Here"
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "commissionsecurity.py", line 38, in <module>
    for ID in FileList():
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: There's no way we can help without seeing `FileList()`, having said that, I suspect `FileList` is a dictionary, so you can't call it..

Comment: FileList and EmailList are both dictionaries.

Comment: `for id in FileList`...  omit the parens.

Comment: Try removing the `()` from `FileList()` (and probably from `FileList()`, too).

Comment: That was it.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Note that you're probably going to run into more trouble, because `for k in EmailList` loops through the *keys* of the EmailList dictionary, so `if ID in k` checks to see if `ID` is a substring of `k` (assuming both are strings). What you likely want is: `for ID in FileList:; if ID in EmailList:; print EmailList[ID]; else print "nothing here"`

Comment: @jme ID is a variable that I used to build my FileList dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like FileList is a dictionary, but you're calling it as if it was a function. I suspect that EmailList is also not a function. You probably want:

```
for ID in FileList:
  for k in EmailList:
    if ID in k:
      print ID
    else:
      print "Nothing Here"
```